# For some reason \lhead creates unwanted indent

Tags: fancyhdr

**Style template (tsu-hl.sty):**

`\ProvidesPackage{tsu-hl}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{adjustbox}
\RequirePackage{mdframed}
\RequirePackage{enumerate}
\RequirePackage{showframe, geometry}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage[unicode, hidelinks]{hyperref}
% Localization
\RequirePackage{ucs}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
% Various symbols
\RequirePackage{ marvosym } % Martin Vogel’s Symbols font
\RequirePackage{ wasysym } % Waldi Sym­bol font
% Needed for the  logo
\RequirePackage{epstopdf} 
\RequirePackage[some]{background}
% To customize headers and footers and frames
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{fancyvrb}
% Custom colours
\definecolor{tsublack}{cmyk}{.10,0,0,0.95}
\definecolor{tsublue1}{cmyk}{1,.4,0,0}
\definecolor{tsublue2}{cmyk}{.85,.3,.19,0}
\definecolor{tsugreen}{cmyk}{.56,0,.58,0}
% Subtitle
\newcommand\@subtitle{}
\@ifundefined{subtitle}{%
    \newcommand{\subtitle}1{%
        \makeatletter%
        \renewcommand\@subtitle{#1}%
        \makeatother%
    }%
}
% Define headers and footers`

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijy4P.png){\markboth{#1}{}}
\lhead{\textbf{\leftmark}}
\rhead{\textbf{\rightmark}}
\lfoot{\textbf{\thepage \quad | \@title \quad | \@subtitle}}

\renewcommand\maketitle{
 \begin{titlepage}
   \newgeometry{left=16mm,top=10mm,right=22mm}
   % TITLES
   \restoregeometry
    \clearpage
  \end{titlepage}
}

\newcommand\makeabstract{
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \hrulefill
 \vfill
 \begin{abstract}
   \begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
    % PAGE with contacts
   \end{minipage}
 \end{abstract}
 \clearpage
}

**Document (whatever.tex):**

`\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tsu-hl}
\usepackage{blindtext}`

\date{23.03.18}
\title{Template}
\subtitle{Template Developement}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\makeabstract
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Title 1}
\blindtext

\subsection{Title 2}
\blindtext[2]

\subsection{Title 3}
\blindtext[3]

\section{Title 2}
\blindtext

\subsection{Title 2}
\blindtext[2]

\subsection{Title 3}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}

**The result:**

[image]

Comment: Isn't this the same question like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425114/fancyhdr-lhead-creates-excess-indent???

Comment: Mistery, my first row with greetings has disapeared and I can not put it back :)
So, Hello everyone!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No.

Comment: Hi Christian, this is the other question.
I've deleted the previous one.

Comment: The document doesn't compile

Comment: @egreg weird...
To compile this sample I've made the following changes:

commented out all "docversion" mentions

Comment: @gray380 There is no contents anyhow, so the issue can't be checked.

Comment: @egreg okay, I've edited the sample and added some content. Should works now.

Comment: Seems the cause of the problem is 'unnumbered' \leftmark. I've changed "\leftmark" with simple text and it was aligned correctly. The question is how to align \leftmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unprotected endlines in `ukraineb.ldf`, I'm afraid.

Minimal example showing the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ukrainian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

x\foreignlanguage{ukrainian}{a}x

\end{document}
```

[image]

The missing `%` comment characters at the end of the line are missing at lines

```
195 216 233 278 281 293 294 304 314 317 318 328 338
```

(actually, only the ones from line 293 onwards are necessary, but I also added the first five for uniformity).

After adding them, the minimal example typesets correctly:

[image]

Comment: oops, you are right. After changing '[english,ukrainian]{babel}' to '[ukrainian, english]{babel}' \leftmark aligns correctly. Sadly.

Comment: @gray380 If I apply the fixes to `ukraineb.ldf` and compile your test file, the indent disappears. I sent a mail to the maintainer.

Comment: Thanks ever so much for your help. I've corrected my ukraineb.ldf and now alignment works.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your vigilance. I have already reloaded the revised version.